# How to stop NSTimer at a specific point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I've created a simple button game that gives the user a point with every tap of the button. The button randomly appears on screen every 1.5 seconds. I want the game to end after 30 seconds or after 20 random button pop ups. I've been using the code below to have the button randomly pop-up on the screen:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.5 target:self
         selector:@selector(moveButton:) 
         userInfo:nil 
         repeats:YES];
```

I've declared the timer in the header file:

```
NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
```

I've read Apple Docs on [Using Timers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW4) but fail to fully understand it. I thought maybe I could use:

```
- (void)countedTimerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer{
  count ++;
  if(count > 20){
     [self.timer invalidate];
     self.timer = nil;
```

But it does not work properly. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to objective-C so I'm not that familiar with how things work.

Comment: Where is count declared? Have you put a breakpoint on count to see what it is every call?

Comment: Can you define "does not work properly"? What behavior are you seeing that you don't want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on your timer method you are passing moveButton method but in below method where you are stopping the timer that method name is different so try this:-

```
  self.timer = [NSTimer     
  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.5 target:self
     selector:@selector(moveButton:) 
     userInfo:nil 
     repeats:YES];
```

//just change the method name below

```
 - (void)moveButton:(NSTimer *)timer{
  count ++;
  if(count > 20){
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;}
```

Comment: To be clear, the issue is that the selector passed to the schedule method is not the same as the method name below.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! While this did not directly answer my question, it did lead my to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new version of Xcode then you don not need to declare

```
NSTimer *timer;
```

and when scheduling a timer you can use

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.5 target:self
         selector:@selector(moveButton:) 
         userInfo:nil 
         repeats:YES]
```

instead of

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.5 target:self
         selector:@selector(moveButton:) 
         userInfo:nil 
         repeats:YES]
```

You are using correct method to stop the timer i.e `invalidate`

You can also refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429571/how-to-stop-nstimer-event) for more clarification.

Please let me know if you solve this problem through the above code.